# Android installLocation auto not allowing move to SD Card?

Tags: java, android

I have an application that I'd like to allow users to move to their SDCard. I have done this on a few previous applications without any trouble by adding the installLocation="auto" flag to the application block of the manifest. For some reason with my current app when I go into application settings I see the button move to SDCard but it is greyed out and not clickable. I was reading the official docs about install location and found a page that talks about [which apps should not allow](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html#ShouldNot) this feature. I guess my question is are there certain features that will actually disable this all together? For instance I'm using a SyncAdapter in my application and the doc says you should not allow move to SDCard when using a SyncAdapter but doesn't indicate that you cannot.

Comment: There are a few features that wont work from external storage, yes. However, I was unaware that the OS would disable this automatically. Usually, I've put in safe guards into app code that lets end users know that certqin featires will be unavailable as/when an app is moved to external storage. There was a wonderful blog post that detailed what apps could and couldn't use, in both internal storage and external, unfortunately I'm on my cell phone. I will find it for you soon though!

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I'd like to read that blog when you get a chance.